# Spring MVC : Saving a string in servlet-context and accessing from java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application, in which I have to save a String value which would be required in many other places but from within the java code. I checked out some solutions on net, but I only found how to declare it, not access it.

I require something like this :

```
<bean id="commontoAllProperty" value="String_value"/>
```

And access above from java code something similar to this :

```
class someClass {

private String getValueInBeanWithId(commontoAllProperty);
}
```

A very vague description but I am going nuts typing that String all the time. Its a FileSystem path by the way. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: if you need it other places then why dont you store in session

Comment: @SpringLearner  need it in backend, not frontend.

Comment: who said session is in front end? can you access session using html/css/js?

Comment: @SpringLearner : Maybe you can be more specific which session you meant, there is also session in Hibernate if you see it that way, I presume you didn't mean that also. So which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value in your properties file and access it all throughout your Spring using the [`@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation. You have an example in [this](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-load-properties-file-value-annotation/) blog post, note the

```
 @Value("${msg}")
 private String msg;
```

Comment: That sounds good, What is the default location for application.properties?

Comment: I saved in resources and it worked. Thanks a lot. I will check the answer in 2 minutes as SO does not allow me now to click on the check mark.

Comment: np, was just about to comment, great, glad it helped

Comment: One last thing, I am saving it like this msg=/home/username   I presume I don't need to give double-quotes.

Comment: no, for backslashes you would have to double it like `\\\`, but for forward its OK to keep as is

Comment: Ok, so finally, msg=\\/home\\/username

Comment: no, I rather meant, keeping it as `/home/username` is fine, you don't need to escape forward slashes, maybe I misslead you with my previous comment :)

Comment: Can you come in chat, it is saving the value in msg is ${msg}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74824/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-master-slave).